# Bash - How to iterate over all files in a folder and wait for completion

Tags: windows, bash, shell, command-line, cmd

I have a little cmd program that records a video, and waits like so taking one argument for the filename:

```
START /WAIT "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Synthesia\Synthesia.exe" --on- 
startup Play  --on-song-end Quit 
"DirectoryHere\%~1"
exit
```

What I cannot figure out is how to loop over all files in a specific folder, and run this program while waiting for it to exit.

This is my current attempt in bash:

```
for filename in /ToBeRendered/*.mid; do
  ./1Processor.cmd $filename
done
```

This gives the error, line1: syntax error near unexpected token '$'do/r

Comment: I have fixed your code pieces so they use four leading spaces; also the indentation of the bash script. The loop looks fine but it is using a directory that is a son of the root directory. Maybe you mean something like `./ToBeRendered/*.mid`. Also, does the bash shell know how to execute a `.cmd` file? Maybe you mean `cmd 1Processor.cmd $filename`.

Comment: Is this Cygwin or MinGW bash running a Windows .cmd script?

Comment: This is using bash from the linux module in windows 10. And I tried what you suggested, I still got: 
test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'est.sh: line 1: `for filename in ./ToBeRendered/*.mid; do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why mixed batch/bash code? Better to use either the one or the other.
For pure batch, this would be something like:

```
for %%a in (\ToBeRendered\*.mid) do (
    START /WAIT "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Synthesia\Synthesia.exe" --on-startup Play --on-song-end Quit "DirectoryHere\%%~nxa"
)
```

Comment: This worked!
As a note to any future people who have this particular issue, changing "DirectoryHere\%%~a" to "DirectoryHere\%%~nxa" will remove the path

Comment: yeah - sure. I forgot... Changed.